# MyBatis - Testing Parameter JdbcType

Tags: junit, mybatis

I have a MyBatis mapper method that inserts data from a POJO into a table.  Initially I was receiving a SQL exception (invalid column type 1111) which turned out to be because one of the values I was inserting into a column was null.

As described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455552/mybatis-error-setting-null-parameter) the solution was to specify the jdbcType of the null variable (setting it to #{myVariable, jdbcType=VARCHAR} worked fine in my case.

My question is how to test this fix?  I have a test method that calls the mapper insert method and I'm inserting a POJO with null values for fields that haven't had their jdbcType specified.  I would expect the test to fail with a SQL exception but the test is passing successfully.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what fails? Mapper details would be useful.